ошибка при импорте нескольких пакетов: missing import path go list, missing import path syntax
Не могу импортировать несколько пакетов, пробовал переустанавливать go на последнюю версию,
Код:
package main

import {
    "fmt"
}

func main() {
    
}



После import используются обычные скобки ()

Спасибо, вчера сам разобрался, невнимательность дает о себе знать.
